# how to pass a parameter value from rdlc report to a method in web forms project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, rdlc, localreport

i have a rdlc report that is bound to following class:

```
public class Product
{
  DataContext context;

  public Product()
  {
    context = new DataContext();
  }
  public List<Product> GetBoughtItemsForUser(string userName)
  {
    //linq query to collect data
    return query.ToList();
  }

  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int Quantity {get;set;}
}
```

in my rdlc i've set the report dataset to GetBoughtItemsForUser. now i want to pass the userName value which is actually the Page.User.Identity.Name so how should i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var p = new Product();

//fill class properties with data

ReportParameter[] params = new ReportParameter[2]; 
params[0] = new ReportParameter("Name ", p.Name , false); 
params[1] = new ReportParameter("Quantity ", p.Quantity , false); 
this.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(params);     
this.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: is this in controller, possible to send parameters from MVC5 controller to rdlc report generator aspx

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy -

If I assume that you are using a Web Application. Just set a Session variable somewhere in the UI layer say :  **Session["exp"] = 6;**

Now assuming your class **Product** is in business layer and your function **GetBoughtItemsForUser** is being called by RDLC file in the dataset.

***Follow these steps to configure the RDLC file -***

1. In the **ObjectDataSource** select **ConfigureDataSource**, then your business layer which contains the method - **GetBoughtItemsForUser**.
2. Now in the **Define Data Methods** window, select your method - **GetBoughtItemsForUser**, here in my case it is GetAllFaculty.

[image]

3. Click Next

[image]

4. Now you will automatically get **Define Parameters** window (only in case of parameterised functions), here choose the **Parameter Source** and give the appropriate parameter name in **SessionField** which you are using in your UI layer, here in my case it is Session type and exp.
5. Hit the finish button and you are done.

> **Note:** You don't have to worry about the conversion of the Session
>   variable into the appropriate type, in most of the cases it will be
>   done automatically. Else you can hit "Show advanced properties".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  rv = ReportViewer1;
            rv.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"Report.rdlc";    
            rv.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportDataSource rs = new ReportDataSource("DataSetName", GetData());
            rv.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rs);                        


            ReportParameter param = new ReportParameter("paramName", paramValue);            
            rv.LocalReport.SetParameters(param); 

            rv.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
               reportParameters.Clear();
                reportParameters.Add(new ReportParameter("prmClientRef", find));
                reportParameters.Add(new ReportParameter("prmClientName", string.Format("{0} {1}",                    allval.Title, allval.ClientName)));

                this.viewerInstance.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
                this.ProductBindingSource.DataSource = storageToPrint.Where(x => x.ClientRef == find).ToList();
                this.viewerInstance.RefreshReport();
                this.viewerInstance.Refresh();
```